# Let $G$ be an Abelian group with $|G| = n$. Let $p$ be prime with $p | n$. Show that the Sylow p-subgroup of $G$ consists of $e$ and ..

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be an Abelian group with $|G| = n$ and let $p$ be prime with $p | n$. Show that the Sylow p-subgroup of $G$ consists of $e$ and all elements whose order is a power of $p$.

Answer: By Sylow 1, $G$ contains a subgroup of order $p$, call it $P$.  Thus for any $a \in P$, $\text{o}(a)|p$, thus $\text{o}(a) = 1$ or $p$.

Comment:  This is where I have gotten on my own.  I am not sure where to go from here or when I need to use the Abelian property of $G$.

Comment: What does Sylow's theorem say about $P$ and any $p$-subgroups of $G$?

Comment: All Sylow p-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate and any p-subgroup of $G$ is contained in a Sylow p-subgroup.

Comment: Right, so consider a subset $X$ such that every $x$ in $X$ has order $p$.

Comment: Hint: every subgroup of an abelian group is...?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it suffices to prove that $G$ has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup. What happens if $G$ has two Sylow $p$-subgroups?